# Can one define alternative algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Context**

I am an engineer by profession, and have read up on math some - where I got the sense that it was common to define alternative algebras for specific domains - where you define the operators, and rules that apply to this system. Whereupon you can use these rules to prove theorems etc. I am on loose footing here though, and a couple of us were debating this.

**Question**

Is this a thing? Can you define such algebras? Or maybe there is some other term for something like this? What am I thinking of? Or maybe I just misunderstood what I was reading.

Comment: please, can you give a reference of what you were reading?

Comment: Yes, you need to be far more specific before we can work out what you are describing.

Comment: I was reading The Universal Computer (among other things). They talk about how math can be seen as as set of symbols and axioms (rules for manipulating these symbols), which are then employed to prove theorems. And they go on from there to derive a notion of computation and the possibility of a universal computer. Computer science has systems like Kleene Algebra.

Comment: You can study various algebraic structures in a textbook on abstract algebra.  Here's Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation seems to be that a mathematical treatment of things often includes defining some symbolic ways to write down operations on the things you're interested in, and some equational reasoning on the expressions you write down in this way.

To answer your direct question: Yes, that is a thing. (Indeed, since you have seen it happen, it would be disingenious to *deny* that it happens). But as its root it's not in itself deeper than that -- just a convenient notation that allows one to express and communicate complex manipulations in less space than it would be to express them in words.

It doesn't take any particular magic or permission to define a symbolic notation for some problem domain -- just write down a definition that's clear enough to be understood by those you're writing for, and presto! you have defined a symbolic notation. You can call it an "algebra" for your problem domain (or a "calculus" if you're feeling particularly high-brow) without offending anyone; these words are vague and flexible enough that there's no hard technical conditions for using them.

The next step up in mathematical sophistication is then to *abstract away* from the concrete meaning of your new symbols and just ask: Suppose we have a system of things and operations that satisfy such-and-such laws; what can we do with them *in general* without knowing what the laws are. This can be useful in two ways: First, to notice that your symbols satisfy laws that are already well-studied (for example you may have your hands on a *ring* or a *group*), which will give you a lot of applicable theory and theorems for free. Second, to replace the structure you were thinking of first with another that satisfies the same laws. This can be a powerful way of extending the usefulness of a mathematical model beyond the particular case it was originally developed for.

There's no widespread technical term for this general way of approaching things, because it is so ubiquitous across basically all of mathematics. It's not even taught as such, except by example -- during a study of mathematics one will have seen a lot of particular instances and hopefully end up comfortable with doing it on one's own when one encounters a domain without a satisfactory existing theory for it.

(Some mathematics departments have courses in "mathematical modeling" that try to be explicit about these things; presumably they have some vocabulary to speak about them. That doesn't mean such vocabulary is in common use among the mathematical community at large, even though everyone *does* the thing described by it).